# mod_rewrite - HTTP to HTTPS for some pages keeping pre-existing rewriting rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file with a few rules that have served well so far. Now I implemented SSL in the website and I need to add a rule to redirect just a single webpage to HTTPS, leaving the rest as it was. Unfortunately but I'm not being able to do so.

**Pre SSL code**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Redirect http://example.com to http://www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]

#Rewrite http://www.example.com/123 to http://www.example.com/data.php?id=123   
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$  data.php?id=$1 [L,NC]

#Rewrite http://www.example.com/about to http://www.example.com/about.php
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php [L,NC]

#Rewrite http://www.example.com/ab123 to http://www.example.com/abdisp.php?id=123
RewriteRule ^ab([0-9]+)$  abdisp.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

Now I need to redirect to HTTPS only the requests for a single specific script. The pre SSL rules need to keep working as they did so far, so all I do is add the following code:

**New HTTP to HTTPS**

```
#If HTTPS is not set and the script being requested is rvservice.php, redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} != on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} rvservice\.php
RewriteRule ^/rvservice\.php(.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This is not working. When I upload this addition to the original code into the server, I get internal server error. I've tried putting this new code at the beginning of the original .htaccess file, but the result is the same. I re-wrote it as a single rewrite rule (no conditions) but I get a redirect loop error. I've been reading posts on SO about HTTP to HTTPS and applied their solutions, but it seems there is something in my old code that does not get along with the new lines. I feel I'm close to the solution, but for the time being it looks I'm closer to clueless. I'll appreciate any pointers in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .htaccess, no / at the beginning in test RewriteRule parameter :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^rvservice\.php(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But if you use `%{REQUEST_URI}` they always start with a /

Comment: Thank you very much. I tested the file with that mistake corrected, but still no success.

Comment: Try now (without www), and tell me what is the problem.

Comment: It works now! You fixed it, thank you so much!!! You have no idea how much time I spent on this in the past three days, I am very grateful for your help. So, please help me understand what I was doing wrong: Was it the www before %{HTTP_HOST}? Do you know why did that render the whole file useless, causing internal server error, rather than just rewriting an invalid url (i.e. https://www.www.example.com/rvservice.php)? Thanks again!

Comment: You had 3 errors: / in RewriteRule, / in REQUEST_URI (but not error), and www.www...